# Simple laravel query

Tags: laravel-5

A simple query to get some additional information to pass to a view, produces an unnecessarily complex result. The result is an array containing an object which has the attribute I'm interested in.

Isn't there a simple way to just get the attribute?

```
   $TheDriver = DB::table('rentals')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'rentals.renter_id')
        ->select('users.name')
        ->where('users.id', '=', $Car->Driver)
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

and `var_dump($TheDriver);` produces this

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#236 (1) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Mr Tourist" } }
```

I'd like to simply get the result "Mr Tourist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pluck()` method to get only certain columns.

```
$TheDriver = DB::table('rentals')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'rentals.renter_id')
        ->select('users.name')
        ->where('users.id', '=', $Car->Driver)
        ->distinct()
        ->pluck('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you are get only one record.

```
$TheDriver = DB::table('rentals')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'rentals.renter_id')
        ->select('users.name')
        ->where('users.id', '=', $Car->Driver)
        ->distinct()
        ->first();
```

get single object above query.